# Prove a Lebesgue Measurable Criterion without Caratheodory Criterion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable iff

$|(-n, n)\cap A|+|(-n, n)\cap A^c|=2n$

for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. ($|A|$ is the outer measure/Lebesgue measure of $A$)

I encountered this problem in Sheldon's *Measure, Integration and Real Analysis* section $2D$ problem 13. One direction is trivial that if $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then the equality holds; however, I'm struggling with the reverse direction. Also we haven't covered the Caratheodory criterion, so I guess it's better not to use it. (Attached is the criterions we've proved and can be used.)[image]

Can I get some help? Thanks in advance.

***Remark:*** in that text book, Lebesgue measurable is defined as "$A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable if $\exists$ Borel set $B\subset A$ s.t. $|A\cap B^c|=0$".

Comment: I would probably concentrate first on proving: if $A \subseteq (-n, n)$ and $|A| + |(-n,n) \setminus A| = 2n$ then $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Recall that a set $A$ is Lebesgue measurable iff there are Borel sets $F$ and $G$ such that $F\subset A\subset G$ such that $|G\subset F|=0$. (the sets that satisfy this condition for what is called the completion $\sigma$-algebra of $|\;|$)
It suffices to assume that $A\subset (-n,n)$ (why?) (***... to be continued***)

Comment: ***... continuation:***Suppose that $A\subset(-n,n)$ is such that
$$2n=|A|^*+|(-n,n)\setminus A|^*$$
Then,  $|A|^*<\infty$ and so, there is a Borel set $B$ such that $A\subset B\subset(-n,n)$ and  $|A|^*=|B|$
Similarly, $|(-n,n)\setminus A|^*<\infty$ and so, there is a Borel set $C$ such that $(-n,n)\setminus A\subset C\subset(-n,n)$ and $|C|=|(-n,n)\setminus A|^*=2n-|A|^*$ by the assumption on $A$.
Then $$(-n,n)\setminus C\subset A\subset B$$ and since both $B$ and $C$ are Borel sets $$|B\setminus\big(-n,n)\setminus C\big)|=|B|-|(-n,n)\setminus C|=|B|-\big(2n-|C|\big)=0$$

Comment: @OliverDiaz  OK I got it; your link and comments really helpd. Thanks a lot.